# Writing a enumerate function using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I received this exercise:

> Write a function `enumerate` that takes a list and returns a list of
>   tuples containing `(index,item)` for each item in the list

My problem is that I cannot insert the index and value in one or a combination of `for` loops. This is the code I managed to make:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c","a","b","c"]
index = 0
for i in a:
    print (index,i)
    index+=1
```

This is roughly the code I want to produce (must be on one line):

```
my_enumerate = lambda x :[(t) for t in x )]
print list(my_enumerate(range(4)))
```

How can I put it all one `lambda` line to get `(value, index)` back? The output should look like:

```
[(0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c")]
```

Comment: looks like it should return a dictionary with index as key.

Comment: Am I missing something or are you trying to reinvent the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

Comment: Or, if it has to be a lambda: `my_enumerate = lambda L: list(ind,item for ind,item in enumerate(L))`

Answer (score 5):

If you can actually index just add the value by indexing:

```
my_enumerate = lambda x :[(t, x[t]) for t in range(len(x))]
print list(my_enumerate(a))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'c')]
```

If not  use zip and put range in the lambda:

```
my_enumerate = lambda x: zip(range(len(x), x))
print list(my_enumerate(a))
```

Comment: Your two examples seem quite different - the first expects the length of the list (and the list itself should also be in scope) and the second the list itself. Why not `lambda a: [(t, a[t]) for t in range(len(a))]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, pasted the wrong  code. Actually irrelevant as the OP cannot index

Comment: I read that as meaning that they were unable to do so, rather than prohibited from it; you may well be right.

Answer (score 1):

```
[(i,a[i])for i in range(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_enumerate = lambda x: [(i, x[i]) for i in xrange(len(x))]
a = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
print my_enumerate(a)
```

outputs:

```
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'c')]
```

EDIT: use `range` instead of `xrange` and `print(...)` instead of `print` if you are using python3

Comment: @H_meir, I thought you said you cannot index?

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) functions solve this problem pretty handily.

```
my_enumerate = lambda seq: zip(range(len(seq)), seq)
```

In Python 2.x, you should use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), and [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it recursively:

```
>>> myenumerate = lambda l, n=0: [] if not l else (lambda ll = list(l): [(n, ll.pop(0))] + myenumerate(ll, n+1)()
```

`list.pop(n)` returns the `n`th  value form the list, and returns it.

The only problem is that you *must* pass in a list:

```
>>> myenumerate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8)]
>>> myenumerate("astring")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
>>> myenumerate(list("astring"))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 's'), (2, 't'), (3, 'r'), (4, 'i'), (5, 'n'), (6, 'g')]
```

However, if you just blindly added calls to `list`, you would't be able to replicate the functionality required without using a slice.

A neat trick for bypassing this requirement is to use another lambda:

```
>>> myenumerate = lambda l, n=0: [] if not l else (lambda ll: [(n, ll.pop(0))] + myenumerate(ll, n+1))(list(l))

>>> myenumerate("astring")
[(0, 'a'), (1, 's'), (2, 't'), (3, 'r'), (4, 'i'), (5, 'n'), (6, 'g')]
```