# How to apply a counter or otherwise index elements using a lambda function?

Tags: python

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145069/how-to-implement-a-counter-using-a-lambda) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303598/writing-a-enumerate-function-using-lambda), but I can't get it to work for my particular use case which is the [`for_each_trace`](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/) functionality for [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) that can be used like this:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = 'line'))
```

Now, consider a case where I'd like to rename all lines in a Plotly figure with `'line' + i`, getting a result like this:

[image]

There are plenty of *other* ways to do that, but I'd really like to know how to do it using

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = 'line')) # pluss some counter functionality
```

One possibility is to use a [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import cycle
titles = cycle([1, 2])
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = 'line ' + str(next(titles))))
```

For which a complete snippet would be:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from itertools import cycle

titles = cycle([1, 2])

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3],))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[3,2,1]))

fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = 'line ' + str(next(titles))))

fig.show()
```

But I would like to be able to do this without the cycle. I've tried using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in a few ways, but without any success. So, does anyone know how to correctly apply `enumerate` or otherwise  incorporate a counter, so that one could index a list within `fig.for_each_trace()`:

```
lst = [1, 2]
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = 'line ' + str(lst[i])))
```

Comment: I'm not a plotly expert, but looking at the docs it seems you can set the name of a trace when you first instantiate it, like `Scatter(..., name='line 1')`, so why use `for_each_trace`?  But if you must use it I don't really see a problem with your approach, though I would use [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), not cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine the counter and the update method together, rather than using a `lambda` I might do something like:

```
def trace_name_updater():
    counter = itertools.count(start=1)
    def update_trace_name(t):
        t.update(name=f'line {next(counter)}')

    return update_trace_name
```

and use it like:

```
fig.for_each_trace(trace_name_updater())
```

In this case the counter will live in the closure of the returned `update_trace_name` function.

Calling `trace_name_updater()` again will give a new counter.

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68846192/how-to-apply-a-counter-or-index-elements-using-a-lambda-function#comment121671606_68846192) is still why you need to do this at all if you can set the trace names upon their initialization, but maybe there is a reason that wasn't explained in your question.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Regarding your question, yes you can get the desired result when building the figure. So this was only an minimal example on how to use `for_each_trace`. This particular function is extremely useful for a variety of more complex use-cases, and I was hoping to learn how to use it in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: Would you consider giving an example on how an approach with `intertools_count` would look like too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean--that's what my answer gives.

Comment: Ah, I thought you could also somehow replace `next(cycle)` with `count` in `fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = 'line ' + str(next(titles))))`

Comment: You could.  Just do `titles = counter(1)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Would you consider adding this to the beginning of your answer? I'm still hoping for even more approaches, but I'll make sure to mark your suggestion as the accepted answer before too long.

Comment: Just accepted your answer. Sorry for the delay, and thanks again!